# Which technology should I use to create Image Processing Web Application

Tags: web-apps, javascript, java, image-processing

I am working in a media company and here **creating images is a daily necessity**. They want me to create a online web application for editing and saving images.

**I am confused which technology should I use** and which tech. will not set boundaries to image editing so i can keep updating as per the requirement. (**such as they might want an overlay, later they might want a gradient so it should adaptable.**)

The requirements are

- Background Image will be taken from Online Somewhere
- Clients logo should be placed
- the background image should be able to be cropped (as per specific
  height and width already set)
- 2 or 3 textbox upon image (in a specific font)

Another image upon Background Image(advance part of it for now not needed)

**example like this** - Image Builder — Vox Media Tools http://apps.voxmedia.com/tools/meme/sbnation/

**I have learned JAVA** and I know JSP but **I dont think that will work**(*let me know if we can*) I am also **open to learn new programming language but it should be productive and work**.

I have not asked questions here if any mistake sorry

Answer (score 3):

Since you already know Java and want to be able to implement all the functionality you need along with keeping the flexibility to add any further image processing to your application as needed, you may want to consider checking out a commercial SDK. Commercial SDKs normally have been stress tested and speed tested so you know they will be productive and work properly and will help you easily implement the functionality you are looking for. Commercial SDKs are designed to make it as easy as possible to add functionality to your application without having to learn exactly how everything works. I would suggest taking a look at the [LEADTOOLS Image Processing SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/image-processing) for your needs.

You could create a Java backend service for loading/processing your images or just use Javascript image processing to manipulate the images directly in the browser itself. The implementation is up to you and how you wish to develop/scale your application.

With LEADTOOLS, you could easily meet the requirements of your application using Java so that you don't have to learn any additional languages:

- LEADTOOLS can take in any of our [150+ supported file formats](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/dh/to/leadtools.topics.leadtools~l.topics.summaryofallsupportedimagefileformats.html) and convert them to a browser supported MIME type so that you can easily display the images in the browser.
- The LEADTOOLS [CombineCommand](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/dh/pe/leadtools.imageprocessing.effects~leadtools.imageprocessing.effects.combinecommand.html) can be used to combine any images into other images so you would be able to adds logos and any other images to your background image.
- The [CropCommand](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/dh/l/leadtools~leadtools.imageprocessing.cropcommand.html) can be used to crop your background image to any width/height that you specify
- You could also use the [LEADTOOLS Annotations](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/annotation) to add any text/arrows/boxes/circles/etc to your images

LEADTOOLS also contains many more [image processing functions](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/image-processing/functions) that you could easily add to your application as the needs arise in the future.

Just as a disclaimer. I work for the company that wrote this library.

Answer (score 1):

Using JAVA is fine, but you need to learn to combine it with some tools like Imagemagick and OpenCV for image processing.

Or you connect from Java to online services that do the required task, such as https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/

Answer (score 0):

If you already know Java I think you should use Java and [Google appengine](http://appengine.google.com). You can also learn the [Java Spring Framework](http://spring.io) for your project. It will work with only the appengine version from google since all you need is a webapp plus image manipulation functionality. If you use Google appengine you will also get Google's nice [Image API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/) as well as their image storing CDN.

Maybe you want to learn a new language for this project, in that case I suggest Go that is fast and new and has the functionality you need and also works with appengine.

You could also use Python, PHP and/or deploy with Amazon Web Services.